# Azure AD Domain Services fails due to unsuccessful connectivity test

Tags: azure-active-directory

Provisioning an instance of Azure AD Domain Services keeps on failing with the following message:

> Error testing domain controller connectivity through PowerShell. A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond xx.xx.xx.xx:5986

Any ideas?

Comment: Several people (including me) having exactly the same issue, but no resolution at time of writing.  Adding link here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/2061/azure-domain-services-creation-powershell-script-f.html?childToView=66976#answer-66976

Answer (score 0):

From : https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/43240

"message" : The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'

"details":[{"code":"InternalError","message":"Error testing domain controller connectivity through PowerShell. A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 20.190.251.173:5986"}]
Other people who have experienced this issue typically had something to do with VPNs, ExpressRoutes, or other special network setups.

I would suggest checking all your network connections and if you have any unique connections

Wait a few hours or until the next day to try again, as there may be some transient network related issues.

If that does not work, try reinstalling AAD DS on the server.

In addition to that : Please take into consideration Domain service instances using Classic Virtual networks are not supported.

Also I want to share with you the documentation for prerequisites, tutorial, network, notifications.
Prerequisites:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-how-subscriptions-associated-directory

Tutorial to create the instance
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/tutorial-create-instance

Network security group rules require to setup the Azure AD DS
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/network-considerations#network-security-groups-and-required-ports

Notifications to assist and manage alerts on the ADDS
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/notifications

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the network security group attached to the AADDS subnet is setup properly.

I was able to reproduce the error when the NSG did not have the required inbound rules
[image]

```
Error: waiting for Domain Service (Name: "", Resource Group: ""): Code="InternalError" Message="Error testing domain controller connectivity through PowerShell. A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 20.198.186.xxx:5986"
```

The following NSG entries fixed the issue described above.
Also make sure you set the DNS servers on the vnet to the IP addresses that will be assigned to the DC before you deploy the AADDS service.

[image]